# 今しかない!! pronouncation

Tags: pronunciation, readings, homophonic-kanji

My memory from playing the VN that the sentence is based off of is 87% certain in the protagonist's voice pronouncing the above as

"YareshKA-nai!!"

and meaning something similar to "I have to do this!!" But I don't know if that is actually what the kanji 今 means or is pronounced as.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

> やるしかない [Yaru shika nai] There is no choice but to do it
>
> 今しかない [ima shika nai] Now or never

今[ima] = now

Comment: So then; a possible translation would be "I have no choice but this now!!" seeing as how shika nai can be translated as 'have no choice' and the 'I' is implied?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Pretty simply, しかない is related to something directly before it. やるしかない is "There is no option other than doing it (regardless of when to do it)". 今しかない is "There is no option other than (doing it) now", "Now is the only chance". But I don't know how you came up with 今...

Comment: What exactly do you want to translate? しかない can indeed be translated as "have no choice but" ([see here](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-shika-nai/)). 今しかない translates to ~"... have no choice but **now**", which in correct English would be "Now or never".